# URL rewrite for Nested URL in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, iis, url-rewriting

i am running react application on IIS, i used URL rewrite for routes configuration, this is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(docs)" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

this code works fine for url like localhost/ReactApp/User,
now i want it to work like localhost/ReactApp/User/Edit but it does not work for child pages it shows blank page,
this issue only comes after build and deployment, please let me know how it can work for /User/Edit nested or Child pages?

Comment: I have same problem but I cant get any routs to work, where do you ut this web.config? Are there other web.config in other dirs?

Answer (score 1):

when you serve the react app from the subfolder you need to set the base name in your routs `<BrowserRouter basename='/path/to/subfolder/'>` or

try below iis url rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{DOCUMENT_ROOT}{URL}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="None" />
    </rule>
    <!--# Fallback all other routes to index.html-->
    <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/path/to/subfolder/index.html" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Should the path for basename be like /appfolder/app/build/? To the build folder?

Comment: @Erik in the site folder oath you have to select the build folder but in the URL rewrite rule, you could set the index file. if the index file is in the subfolder add the subfolder oath.