# Need direct link for admin panel in React js App

Tags: reactjs

My app is opening with base url fine.
like
https://mentorlogix.com/pricebuilder/
I created a sapreat link for admin panel
https://mentorlogix.com/pricebuilder/adminlogin but when I open this directly then display Page not found.
But If I open this link internally from opened app then working fine.
I defined these link in my router too.

```
   {
   path: "/adminlogin",
   name: "adminlogin",
   icon: "ni ni-key-25 text-info",
   component: AdminLogin,
   layout: "/auth"
   }
```

And my index.js

```
   <Redirect from="/adminlogin" to="/auth/adminlogin" />

   <Redirect from="/" to="/auth/login" />
```

Can any one help pleae

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewrite for Nested URL in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63557066/url-rewrite-for-nested-url-in-reactjs)

Comment: No this is not useful